# Posibles problemas de compilación(?)

Tags: php

He visto que algunos desarrolladores suelen agregar un *lanzador* de excepciones adicional, como en el siguiente código:

```
function Implement(){
    if ($prepared){
        return Act::Composition('kill');
    }else{
        return Act::Generate(function(){
           return Act::CreateObject('sampling'); 
        });
    }
    throw new Exception('You should not be here.'); // <-- Redundancia aquí, se supone que jamás llegará aquí, o eso considero yo...
}
```

Aunque es claro que no pasará del else, *porque sí o sí tendrá que entrar en el else* algunos programadores prefieren agregar un *lanzador* de excepciones extra, por qué?

Pueden existir problemas al momento de compilar, como para agregar una pequeña redundancia?
De donde viene/pudo venir esa prevención?

En algunos casos en vez de `throw` también puede ser un `return` extra.
Me ha dejado inquieto a saber cuál es la razón para hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

No, no debería estar, no es necesario, eso refleja una falta de confianza en la tecnología. Para más información puedes leer [este post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/).

En resúmen, está mal que esté ahí, no es recomendable, solo oscurece el código, algunos lenguajes como Java ni siquiera permitirían esa línea de código por rebundante. Quiero pensar que antes tenía utilidad y luego cambiaron la función y por miedo la dejaron, pero es un error lógico que el compilador te va a dejar pasar por ser relajado, pero no tiene utilidad, es solo código basura que bajo ninguna lógica será ejecutado y que ahora hay que tener en tu base de código.

**Edit**

Extraigo de link:

> A pair of studies performed [in 1973 and 1984] found that, of total
>   errors reported, roughly 95% are caused by programmers, 2% by systems
>   software (the compiler and the operating system), 2% by some other
>   software, and 1% by the hardware. Systems software and development
>   tools are used by many more people today than they were in the 1970s
>   and 1980s, and so my best guess is that, today, an even higher
>   percentage of errors are the programmers' fault.

En español:

> Un par de estudios ... encontraron que del total de errores
>   reportados, 95% son causados por programadores, 2% por sistemas de
>   software y 1% por hardware... mi apuesta es que hoy, hay un porcentaje
>   más grande que son la culpa del programador

Así que si, pueden existir errores, pero casi siempre serán culpa del desarrollador y no de las librerías (digo, si usas librerías de calidad), solo para iluminar más el caso de que quien puso esa línea debió haber sido por inseguridad o desconocimiento del lenguaje y no por una razón lógica o válida

Comment: Aunque no estoy de acuerdo que la falla siempre es el programador, porque pueden existir bugs o glitches en un lenguaje de programación, si estoy de acuerdo con que hay miedo, +1

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta para enfatizar el punto, claro que hay bugs, pero no puedes programar defensivamente contra tus propias herramientas

Answer (score 1):

Sobraría,  ya que la función al llegar al return devuelve la función y la finaliza automáticamente  hasta hay. Esto hace que las lineas de código que van después del return no las ejecutaría.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad de StackOverflow, es muy cierto lo que dices, pero como cierto también es muy obvio :) Pero mi duda es por qué tienen esas costumbres, gracias por tu respuesta +1